# Angular 6 / Typescript Get key names from Json object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I have some data which I'm getting from jsonplaceholder and I want to add it to a table.

The data looks like this:

```
[{
    userId: 1,
    id: 1,
    title: "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    body: "quia et suscipit suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  }
]
```

The first thing I need to do for the table as to popular the

But in order to do that I need to be able to get the key names and add it to another object so that I can dynamically popular the html table heading.

My question is how can I create a list of keys from an object?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Object.keys(obj)` is what you're looking for. It returns an array of keys.

You can also loop over keys with :

```
for(let key in obj) {
    // Whatever you want to do with key or obj[key]
}
```